# FindOne mongo return null

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to find film and if it doesn't exist yet, add it in database.

```
let film = Films.findOne({ "id" :id }, function(err, doc) {
   if (err) throw err;
   else console.log("Film is "+doc);
});

if (!film){
   film = {"id" : id};
   Films.insertOne(film);
}
```

`console.log` gives `null`, so there are no errors but it can't create new film in database. Could you please say what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. The problem has to do with async. You need the `findOne` to return before you call the `if` statement.

```
Films.findOne({ "id" :id }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err){
        // error
        throw err;
    } else if (doc) {
        // film exists
        console.log("Film is "+doc);
    } else {
        // film doesn't exist
        var film = new Films({"id" : id});
        film.save();
    }
});
```

That code will find one item with `id` = to your `id` variable and call the function provided when complete, passing in any errors and the document it found (or `null` if no document was found).

Then will print the document if it exists, otherwise it will create a new film object and save it to the database.

Comment: it gives an error:
`events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Films_1.Films.insertOne is not a function`

Comment: @BububuMalibu Awesome! Consider accepting if it helped you. Happy coding!!

Comment: @BububuMalibu There should be a green check mark below the question :)